# How could I generalize a http response handler in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, promise

I'm writing a rest api for a node application, and I find myself rewriting something like the following a lot:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  databaseCall()
  .then( (results) => {
    if (results != null) {
      res.status(200).send(results);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Request error: " + err.stack);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  })
}
```

I would like to refactor the response portion, so I can do something like

```
databaseCall()
.then(handleResponse)
```

where `handleResponse` would take care of the whole response/catch process.
But I can't quite figure out how to do that. The databaseCall method varies depending on the endpoint - sometimes it takes a parameter, sometimes not. I could make a generic function expression that takes the databaseCall result and stick it in the promise chain, but I don't know how I could access the response object inside that function. I know I could add another function to combine everything, like so:

```
function(databaseCall, parameter, req, res, next) {
  databaseCall(parameter)
  .then( (results) => {
    if (results != null) {
      res.status(200).send(results);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
    console.log("Request error: " + err.stack);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  })
}
```

But that seems ugly since databaseCall could have 0-several parameters. I'd think there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can't you just make a new function that does what you want and call that anywhere you need it?  Decide what parameters it makes sense to pass it so you can have the most general implementation.

Comment: Like the last function I listed? I know I could do something like that, I guess that just seems like a sloppy solution. Maybe I'm just being picky.

Comment: For us to advise on the best way to refactor, we have to see a representative sample of all the things you are trying to incorporate in your refactor so we know what the overall objectives are.  Since you've really only shown one code snippet, I don't know what all the refactor really needs to accomplish.  But, yes the one function you show is one way to approach it.

Comment: FYI, a more generic way to pass arbitrary parameters is to pass an object and let the caller assign whatever properties to that object are appropriate for the given situation.  Your wrapper function then just passes through the object to the underlying database call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably thinking in the right direction, you just need to take it a step further and keep the db call outside the generic handler, and pass it as a promise instead

```
// generic handler for db promise
// the promise is created outside and passed as arg
function responseFromDb(databaseCallPromise, res) {
  databaseCallPromise
  .then((results) => {
    if (results != null) {
      res.status(200).send(results);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Request error: ${err.stack}`);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
}

// handler per request, only needs to create db call with the desired params
// and pass it to the generic handler, which will take care of sending the response
function(req, res, next) {
  responseFromDb(databaseCall(param1, param2), res)
}
```

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was hoping for. I couldn't wrap my mind around the fact that passing the call itself as a parameter is equivalent to passing a promise. Resolves the varying parameters issue. Thanks.

Comment: @cweber105 you're welcome. If this solution works for your question, please accept the answer.